# Javascript controls not working for Bootstrap modal (and generally)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using javascript to control a modal for a log in and registration page.

However I cant seem to get the javascript to fire.

Here is the header for my page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>My Site </title>
<link rel="icon" href="myfavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.1/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Landing Page CSS -->
    <link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- jQuery - UI CSS - Both v 1.11 and 2.1 -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Starts all the Javascript-->

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>

<!-- Javascript for the admin page -->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery - Both v 1.11 and 2.1 -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Validator-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.1/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

<!-- The Validator for the forms-->   
<script src="js/validator.js"></script>

<!-- My Custom Javascript functions-->   
<script src="js/mymain.js"></script>
```

My Login Function are held within the /js/mymain.js script. I also have the following call to the login function in a document.ready() within the `<head>` of this page.

```
$('#loginBtn').click(function(e){
alert('cliked');
    e.preventDefault();
    login();
    });
```

The problem is that the alert given above is not firing, which suggests that there is something broken in the javascript, but I cant work out what it is.

All the Modals are as per the Bootstrap site, and are ID'd appropriately. Its just a problem with the Javascript/Jquery.

Comment: I was silly. Needed to call the Jquery before the Bootstrap.js - Not super sure why, but the modal seems to be working now.

Comment: because the $ you are using in bootstrap.js gets its functionality from jquery.js .. So jquery has to be loaded first.. otherwise you will get $ undefined error in Console... :)